# how to access to different database in the same application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

Here's a typical connection string we have `Data Source, Initial Catalog, User ID, and Password.`

I'd like to know if it's possible to access another source and/or database while the application is running without having to change the connection string values.

The application is upgraded to new environment, pointing to a new source/database. Not all the data are in the new database. I'd like to keep working and accessing the old database to test some part of the application. So while most of the Is that feasible?

Thanks for helping

Comment: You need to maintain two connections and switch those connections to go back and forth.  Or, provide access to the old database from new database by having a common user

Comment: Simply add the new connection string in your Web.Config and refer to that in your code?

Comment: We do this constantly, sometimes we even have the same application talking to both Oracle and SQL-Server at the same time, or at least when initialized. In cases where we want the application to connect to a dev SQL while in dev or testing, and a production SQL once deployed, we use Visual Studio web.config.debug/.release to transform the tables during deployment.